# Show plus sign in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there a filter in Django to print a positive float variable with a plus sign?

`e.g. 1.234 as +1.234`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should be able to use `stringformat`, which takes the same parameters as `printf`:

```
{{ yourvalue|stringformat:"+d" }}
```

More good information here: https://pyformat.info/#number_sign

Good luck!